# Angular `$watchCollection` returning undefined oldVal in test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am running a Jasmine spec on a directive compiled from markup.

With the following method in a directive:

```
 scope.$watchCollection 'x', ->
    console.log arguments
```

And the following test:

```
it "adds to array", ->
  scope.$apply( ->
    scope.x = []
  )
  scope.$apply( ->
    scope.x.push(0)
  )
```

I get the following console output:

```
[undefined, undefined, Scope]
jasmine-specs.js:63717 [Array[0], undefined, Scope]
jasmine-specs.js:63717 [Array[1], undefined, Scope]
```

This seems broken.  I would expect the second argument of the last line to be "Array[0]", the previous value of the collection.  Why would this not be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same thing [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXR22DqbOhHRY6EPQfMk?p=info), and I was confused too until I saw this in the [angular docs for $watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection):

> The `oldCollection` object is a copy of the former collection data. Due to performance considerations, `theoldCollection` **value is computed only if the `listener` function declares two or more arguments**.

This statement is referring to this code:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('x', function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

vs this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('x', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

(I know this is not using the lambda syntax, but it's the same solution)

So the `oldCollection` will always be undefined unless you actually declare the 1st and 2nd arguments to hold the new and old value. Then it will show up as `Array[0]` as you expected. This [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NXoVHCtWQweRLNsYwjZI?p=info) will show that.

**Edit:** I think the other syntax would be:

```
scope.$watchCollection 'x', (new, old) ->
    console.log arguments
```

Comment: isn't there a little typo there? args should be `(newVal, oldVal)`.